# mvn deploy failed with permission denied error

Tags: java, maven, sql-maven-plugin

mvn deploy just worked fine until I used following piece in my pom file

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Error: Permission denied while uploading artifacts to Nexus
Reasonphrase : Forbidden

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Please post your full pom file and the exact log information about the permission...

Comment: Hi, pom file is simple pom file for a springboot app, my jenkins job is failing after I introduced this plugin. Uploading to nexus, my-artifact,pom 01:06:27 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project : Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact <my-artifact>, Access denied to: <my-artifact>, ReasonPhrase: Forbidden.

Comment: You not configured the credentials correctly in your settings.xml file..If you have really seen `forbidden` it means you are not allowed to deploy files into that given repository...check which one is defined in `distributionManagement` ...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, my deploy job was running fine until I introduced this plugin block in pom. So distributionManagement differs from plugin to plugin ?